# PHP MySQLI (OOP?) - The code doesn't work at all

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm kinda new to the OOP(? If this IS OOP, I don't know) language, and I'm trying to make a simple login-proccess, with MySQLi. The problem are, that the code doesn't work. I can't login (and It's not showing me any errors) and I can't register an new account (same problem) - It's like the code are dead or something.

I'm not sure I've done it right, but this is my best, so far. 'cause I'm new to OOP(?).

Index.php:

```
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));

                    $userControl = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
                    $userControlResult = $mysqli->query($userControl);

                    if($mysqli->num_rows($userControlResult) > 1) {
                        $userRow = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($userControlResult);

                        $dbid = $userRow['id'];
                        $dbuser = $userRow['username'];

                        $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                        header("location: me.php");
                        die();
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='errorField'>Anv&auml;ndarnamnet eller l&ouml;senordet &auml;r fel!</div>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

I suppose that if I can solve the first error, I can solve the second too.
Thanks!

Comment: Your if statement is checking to see if you have more than 1 row - that should be `= 1`, I think. Also, you should be using a prepared statement and binding variables on your SELECT, too - you're using mysqli_, so you can use its built-in features to make your code more secure.

Comment: To piggyback, make sure that `session_start()` is being called somewhere. If not, you can't access `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli()` together?

Comment: Do you have something like this earlier in your code: `$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");`?

Comment: In addition to everything already said, make sure that the password you put in the database has been hashed with MD5.  Otherwise, it will never find your user.  Also, I would recommend using something stronger than MD5, such as SHA256.  PHP has support for this out of the box. Check this out: [PHP Hash Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: I have solved the problem now, but the session_start() doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to fix this? My code: http://prntscr.com/1g770p AND THE SESSION_START IS ON TOP OF THE SITE!

Answer (score 1):

Many things I would recommend changing about your code:

- Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you're using mysqli.  You can't mix these APIs.
- No need to escape a string returned by `md5()`, because it's guaranteed to contain only hexadecimal digits.
- Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` anyway -- use parameters instead.
- Always check if `prepare()` or `execute()` return **false**; if they do, then report the errors and exit.
- You can get a mysqli result from a prepared statement using `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`.
- Don't `SELECT *` if you don't need all the columns.  In this case, you already have `$username` so all you really need to fetch is the `id` column.
- No need to check the number of rows returned, just start a loop fetching the rows (if any).  Since you exit inside the loop, your "else" error clause will be output only if the loop fetches zero rows.
- Consider using a stronger password hashing function than MD5.  Also, add a salt to the password before hashing.  Read [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);

  $userControl = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?";
  if (($userControlStmt = $mysqli->prepare($userControl)) === false) {
    trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    die();
  }

  $userControlStmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

  if ($userControlStmt->execute() === false) {
    trigger_error($userControlStmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    die();
  }

  $userControlResult = $userControlStmt->store_result();

  while($userRow = $userControlResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userRow["id"];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    header("location: me.php");
    die();
  }

  // this line will be reached only if the while loops over zero rows
  echo "<div class='errorField'>Anv&auml;ndarnamnet eller l&ouml;senordet &auml;r fel!</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good command to enter at the top of the script (under the

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will display any errors on your script without needing to update the php.ini (in many cases). If you try this, and need more help, please post the error message here and I'll be able to help more.

Also, if you are using `$_SESSION`, you should have

```
session_start();
```

at the top of the script under the

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your php is set to show errors in the php.ini file. You'll need to do some research on this on your own, but it's fairly easy to do. That way, you'll be able to see what the error is and go from there.

Comment: not really an answer, more of a suggestion better suited for comments section.